# how to find the elements to get it separate

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on my PHP to parsing the contents from the elements.

I have the ids of `<span id="time1">` and `<span id="title1">` for the elements. I'm trying to parse the `time1`, `time2`, `time3`, `time4`, `time5`, `time6`, `time7`, `time8`, `time9` and `title1`, `title2`, `title3`, `title4`, `title5`, `title6`, `title7`, `title8`, `title9` elements which I'm using `span` as the id.

I will get the input of the `time1`, `time2`, `time3`, `time4`, `time5`, `time6`, `time7`, `time8`, `time9` and `title1`, `title2`, `title3`, `title4`, `title5`, `title6`, `title7`, `title8`, `title9` together which I want to get the list of `time1` to `time9` and `title1` to `title9` in separate.

Here is the input:

```
7:00 PMMelissa & Joey - Born to Run7:30 PMMelissa & Joey - More Than Roommates8:00 PMMelissa & Joey - Accidents Will Happen8:30 PMBaby Daddy - From Here to Paternity9:00 PM
```

Here is the output of get-listing:

```
<span id="time1">7:00 PM</span> - <span id="title1">Melissa & Joey -  Born to Run</span><br></br>
<span id="time2">7:30 PM</span> - <span id="title2">Melissa & Joey -  More Than Roommates</span><br></br>
<span id="time3">8:00 PM</span> - <span id="title3">Melissa & Joey -  Accidents Will Happen</span><br></br>
<span id="time4">8:30 PM</span> - <span id="title4">Baby Daddy -  From Here to Paternity</span><br></br>
<span id="time5">9:00 PM</span>
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

$xml .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
$xml .= '
<tv generator-info-name="www.mysite.com/xmltv">';

$baseUrl = file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php');

$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$domdoc->recover=true;
//@$domdoc->loadHTMLFile($baseUrl);
@$domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);

//$links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('test');
//$links = $domdoc->getElementById('test');
$links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');

$data = array();
foreach($links as $link)
{  
  //echo $domdoc->saveXML($link);
  if($link->getAttribute('href'))
  {
     if(!$link->hasAttribute('id') || $link->getAttribute('id')!='streams')
     {
       $url = str_replace("rtmp://", "", $link->getAttribute('href'));
       $url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $link->getAttribute('href'));
       //echo $url;
       //echo "<br>";
       $sdoc = new DOMDocument();
       $sdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
       $sdoc->recover=true;
       @$sdoc->loadHTMLFile($url);
       $spans = $sdoc->getElementsByTagName('span');
       $query = parse_url($url)['query'];
       $channel_split = explode("&", $query)[0];
       $channel = urldecode(explode("=",$channel_split)[1]);
       $id_split = explode("&", $query)[1];
       $my_id = urldecode(explode("=",$id_split)[1]);
       //echo $my_id;
       //echo '<channel id='.$my_id.'>';
       //echo $spans->nodeValue;

       $flag=0;
       foreach($spans as $span)
       {
         echo $span->nodeValue;
         $starttime=$span->nodeValue;
         //echo "<programme channel='".$my_id." ".$channel." start='".$starttime."' stop='".$stoptime."'>";

     if($flag>0)
     {
       //echo "<programme channel='".$my_id." ".$channel." start='".$starttime."' stop='".$stoptime."'>";
       $stoptime=$starttime;
       $flag=1;
     }
     else
     {
       $stoptime=$starttime;
     }
       }
     }
  }
}
?>
```

Can you please tell me how I can create the arrays for the domdocument to get the element id of `time1` to `time9` to make it separate with `title1` to `title9`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = '<span id="time1">7:00 PM</span> - <span id="title1">Melissa & Joey -  Born to Run</span><br></br>
<span id="time2">7:30 PM</span> - <span id="title2">Melissa & Joey -  More Than Roommates</span><br></br>
<span id="time3">8:00 PM</span> - <span id="title3">Melissa & Joey -  Accidents Will Happen</span><br></br>
<span id="time4">8:30 PM</span> - <span id="title4">Baby Daddy -  From Here to Paternity</span><br></br>
<span id="time5">9:00 PM</span>';


$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("*/span[@id='time1']");

print_r($elements);

foreach($elements as $e){
  echo $e->nodeValue;
}
```

?>

Comment: Thank you very much for this Burak Öztürk, I can see it is working now. Cheers for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

i hope it will help you, i used this a years ago..

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm sorry but I found simplehtmldom are too slow which i will find the errors everytime and I find domdocument are better than using simplehtmldom. So how i can get the list of `time1` to `time9` using with domdocument?

Comment: are there any way if i can create the arrays for `time1` to `time9` and create another arrays for `title1` to `title9` to get the list of time and title?

Comment: You can look here: http://www.binarytides.com/php-tutorial-parsing-html-with-domdocument/

Comment: I understand you are busy, but I tried this: `$time1_span = $sdoc->getElementById('time1'); foreach($time1_span as $time1)
       {
         echo $time1->nodeValue;
       }
` i will not get the return strings. do you know why?

Comment: I can put the `echo $time1->nodeValue;` before the foreach loops which it works fine but when I put the `echo $time1->nodeValue;` under the foreach loop, I can't get pass it. Any idea?

Comment: so how i can create the array for $time1_span, $time2_span, $time3_span..etc in order to get pass the foreach loop?